# IMDB information Graber in Excel

Tags: internet-explorer, excel, vba

i have been trying to grab infor mation from IMDB to a Excel Sheet and 
so Far i got to the below vba code in excel.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = Range("A2").Row And _
    Target.Column = Range("A2").Column Then
        Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
        'IE.Visible = True
        IE.Navigate "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt" & Range("A2").Value
        Do
        DoEvents
        Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
        Set Doc = IE.document
        Dim sDD As String
        sDD = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("h1")(0).innerText)
        IE.Quit
        Dim aDD As Variant
        aDD = Split(sDD)
        Range("B2").Value = aDD(0)
    End If
End Sub
```

and now i want to `Range("A2")` to multiple cells or  any other codes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is probably what you would be after.
 It will grab a name you have input into a column in excel.
Then Search IMDB using Googles, "I'm feeling lucky" then grab the "correct" labelling of the movie including year.

If you want the IMDB reference, you could use the tt######### from the address bar or tag.

```
'tools > references > Microsoft Internet Controls & Microsoft HTML Object Library need to be ticked

Private Sub Grab_IMDB_Data()
Dim rCurrent As Range
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim aDD As Variant
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim NoM As Integer 'Number of Movies
Dim arraymovies() As String 'dynamic array
Dim searchTerm As String

NoM = 1
x = 1 'cell ref hoz
y = 2 'cell ref vert
i = 0

    While Worksheets(3).Cells(y + i, x) <> "" 'finds amount of movies in your list
        NoM = NoM + 1
        i = i + 1
    Wend

ReDim arraymovies(NoM) As String 'sets array to length of movie list

    For i = 1 To NoM 'adds list to array
        arraymovies(i) = Worksheets(3).Cells(i + 1, x).Value 'fills array with values in cells for quick reference
    Next

On Error Resume Next

    For i = 1 To NoM

        'IE.Visible = True
        IE.Navigate "http://google.com/search?btnI=1&q=imdb " & arraymovies(i) 'uses im feeling lucky IMDB
        Do
             DoEvents
        Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

        Set Doc = IE.document

        sDD = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("h1")(0).innerText)
        IE.Close
        arraymovies(i) = sDD
    Next

    For i = 1 To NoM 'overlays changes
        Worksheets(1).Cells(i + 1, x) = arraymovies(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

so you might have a column say B:B filled with these imdb tags, then what you can do in stead of the if is use a for each loop, please be aware that I haven't tested for the InternetExplorer interaction part:

```
Private Sub Grab_IMDB_Data
 Dim rCurrent as Range
 Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
 Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
 Dim aDD As Variant
 Dim sDD As String

 For each rCurrent in Range("B:B").Cells
      If rCurrent.Value <>"" Then
           'IE.Visible = True
           IE.Navigate "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt" & Range("A2").Value
           Do
                DoEvents
           Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

           Set Doc = IE.document

           sDD = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("h1")(0).innerText)
           IE.Quit

           aDD = Split(sDD)
           rCurrent.Offset(0 ,1).Value = aDD(0)
      End If
  Next rCurrent

End Sub
```

One note for consideration: it might not be legal to actually grab all this from the imdb website.

Comment: not working..
in the imdb website each movie they have give url as `http://www.imdb.com/title/ttxxxxxxx` and i am filling column A from A2 to A100 (A2:A100) with the xxxxxxx from 0000001 to 0000100 and when i run the script the result for each url `http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0000001 to tt0000100` will show corresponding to each column A in Column B..

Comment: Then you can simply change the ranges for it. Apply so in the code above. If you have NO coding experience please hire a freelancer to make it work for you.